Can you measure correlation between only the seasonal components of 2 time series?
I have time series data for scorpion sting accidents and environmental data (rain). There is an upward trend in scorpion stings, but there is also a seasonal component which seems to match the rain (which has no trend whatsoever, but is strongly seasonal climate with many dry months ).
I decomposed both time series in R-studio and ran a spearman-rho correlation between their seasonal components, and there is a strong correlation (~0,80); my idea was showing that: the cases are raising irregardless of rainfall, but during rainy months there are more cases. Is this a statistic valid method (measuring correlation of seasonal components) or is a spurious correlation? Is it also a valid conclusion ?
Another analysis that showed some correlation was % of cases for the year vs % of rain for the year; is that a better approach?

It seems valid, but there is likely a better approach.
Since your "seasonality" actually seems driven by rainfall, you could directly model the dependence of stings on rainfall rather than month.
For example, you could try fitting various Arima models to your data that account for rainfall as a regressor. If you have a linear trend, you could load the "forecast" package in R, then with your data sorted from oldest to newest, estimate something like:
Arima(stings,order=c(0,0,0),xreg=cbind(trend,rainfall),include.constant=TRUE)

where the variable "trend" is just an index = {1,2,...,N}. This will estimate the model:
$$ stings_t = \mu + \beta_1 t + \beta_2 rainfall_t +\varepsilon_t$$
If your trend is stochastic, rather than linear, you could instead estimate:
Dstings <- diff(stings)
rainfall <- rainfall[2:length(rainfall)]    
Arima(Dstings,order=c(0,0,0),xreg=rainfall,include.constant=TRUE)

$$ \Delta stings_t = \mu + \beta_2 rainfall_t +\varepsilon_t$$
where $\beta_2$ will give the association between rainfall and the change in stings.
If there is autocorrelation in the errors, or residual seasonality, these can be captured by setting the appropriate "order" terms in the Arima function, and specifying the optional seasonal order terms. Alternatively, you can have these chosen for you automatically by using the auto.arima function in place of the Arima function.
The test of association between stings and rainfall would then be a t-test on the $\beta_2$ parameter.
